# VLOOKUP return an array of all matches in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

I need to return an array of all matches for a VLOOKUP then return a value based on what's in the array. The data looks like this

```
product_style        color         in_stock
11111                Green          0
11111                Blue           1
22222                Green          1
22222                Blue           0
22222                Red            0
33333                Green          1
```

I need a vlookup to find all products based on the style, and find out if it has any colors in stock then return 0 or 1. Its easy to find the first value

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,A2:C7,3,0)=1,1,0)
```

The problem is that it will just grab the first occurrence and return that value.

A possible solution is to add them all up, since I am using 0 or 1 for in_stock, so

```
=IF(VLOOKUP TOTAL > 0,1,0)
```

That would work if I could get the VLOOKUP TOTAL

The only restriction is that the resulting array must all be in a single cell, I've seen this answer, but the resulting array shows up in multiple cells

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx

Comment: As you saw in that article, VLOOKUP does not return information on multiple matches, only the first match (or none). If summing the `in_stock` values will work for you try `=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,11111)`, which should return `1` in the example data.

Comment: This sounds like a good use for a pivot table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to find the quantity on stock for a particular style ?

Comment: Alexandre - No, its a boolean of yes or no, I want to know if any colors are in stock.
Andy - That worked, if you want to submit an answer I would accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumifs will work, as described in the comment above, but it is not available in Excel 2003 and earlier. Here are a few possibilities

SUMIF works in all versions of Excel, but it only accepts one condition

```
=SUMIF(A2:A7,"11111",C2:C7)
```

SUMIFS accepts multiple conditions, but only works in Excel 2007 and up

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"11111")
```

SUMPRODUCT works with multiple conditions and is available in all versions of Excel. It will be slower than any of the above formulas, but this will only be noticeable in large datasets.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7="11111")*C2:C7)
```

The array formula below needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (don't type the curly braces. Excel will add them automatically.) It works in all versions of Excel and is a tad slower than SUMPRODUCT.

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A7="11111",C2:C7,0))}
```

So, if you have Excel 2003 or need the backwards compatibility, go with SUMIF. It's the fastest option that works in all versions.

Answer (score 0):

I created named ranges for COLOR and PROD_ID to make this more readable:

=IF(VLOOKUP(COLOR,IF(A1:A6=PROD_ID,**B1:C6**,""),2,0),1,0)

Hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when you enter this formula, it is an array formula, and will not work if don't enter it that way. I will explain it from the inside out (as well as I can, because I do not full understand part of it. This is assuming data is in cells A1:C6 (no headers).

Entering as an array function allows the inner IF to cycle through A1:A6=PROD_ID, for every match, it adds a tuple to a temporary array, so after the inner loop completes, it returns the array {"Green", 0; "Blue", 1; "",""; "",""; "",""; "",""; } - in a more readable format, this is (please forgive my horrible "more readable" format):

---Col1---|--Col2

-"Green"-|--0

--"Blue"--|--1

---""-------|--""

---""-------|--""

---""-------|--""

---""-------|--""

Your vlookup then runs against this, returning 1 (row 2) to the outer-most if. Unfortunately, I'm a bit fuzzy on how the bolded part of my formula works, I just know it will return the appropriate row in that range as needed.